# Proxy to allow two different networks an internet connection

Tags: proxy, shared-access

I need to set up a proxy server to allow two different networks to share an ADSL internet connection but not allow the two networks to access one another. 
How do I do this?

Comment: 1. what you mean proxy? NAT is enough or not? 2. how is your network like, do you can have a server that both network able to connect?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a [Squid Proxy Server](http://www.squid-cache.org/)  This needs to run on a Linux machine. Setting up Squid takes some time, but there are very good tutorials that can give you step by step instructions on how to achieve this. Like this how-to [Installing Squid](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch32_:_Controlling_Web_Access_with_Squid#Restricting_Web_Access_By_Time)

If you want a Windows solution for a proxy server you can try [FreeProxy](http://www.handcraftedsoftware.org/)  Both of these programs are OpenSource and requires no licensing.

I have been using Squid for the past 7 years with Dansguardian for the webfiltering.  Can't find anything that can come close to beating it.